I'm building a safari extension. How can I take a screenshot of non visible part?
I'm building an extension for safari.
I'm using captureVisibleTab to take a screenshot. But it has a problem. When I scroll down the page, it doesn't capture the top of the page. I know it's a default behavior, but I want to take a screenshot of the top of the page even when I scroll it down.
I don't need to take a whole page, I just want to take a screenshot from the top of the page.
How can I achieve it?
I found chrome.desktopCapture but it seems it's only for chrome.

It was simple.
I could scrolling up to the top of the page by adding the following code in background.js.
background.js:
    await browser.scripting.executeScript({

      target: { tabId: tabId },

      func: () => {

        window.scrollTo(0, 0);

      },

    });

Also, I added scripting in permissions in manifest.
